# dynamically added input element doesn't return value in script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

After adding dynamically input element (with class "dateValidation") inside static div ( with class "workItems") I use this to provide onclick function:

```
$(".workItems").on("click", ".dateValidation", function()
{...});
```

and when I in function above run f.e

```
alert(this);
```

I get: [object HTMLInputElement] (I think it's good)

but, when I run:

```
alert(this.val());
alert(this.hasClass("dateValidation"));
```

Nothing happens. What is wrong with this code? How Can I get f.e value of this input element?

Answer (score 4):

`this` is a DOM element, you need to convert it to jquery element before running jquery functions on it

```
alert($(this).val());
alert($(this).hasClass("dateValidation"));
```

Comment: @nolbadi111 is your `_checkingDate` function expecting a DOM object or jquery object

Comment: $(".workItems").on("click", ".dateValidation", function()
   {_settingPlaceholderDate(this);}
and
function _settingPlaceholderDate(providedDate){  $(providedDate).attr("placeholder","dd-mm-rrrr");};

Comment: @nolbadi111 is this working fine? what is the question?

Comment: No, it doesn't work, but only on dynamically added input. When I use _settingPlaceholderDate(this) on static element everything is correct.

Comment: Didn't understand this. Can you add the actual problem you are facing in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).val()` and `$(this).hasClass("dateValidation");` instead of this.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the DOM object, whereas $(this) is the jQuery wrapper.

Using `this`, you can call DOM methods/attributes but not jQuery methods. And when using `$(this)`, you can call jQuery methods not DOM methods.

In your case you're trying to access the jQuery method `val()` using DOM object `this` which is wrong. So you've to use jQuery methods using jQuery wrapper `$(this)`.

Updated script would be like this.

```
alert($(this).val());
alert($(this).hasClass("dateValidation"));
```

*Hope this will help to you find issue !!*